# SQL query - Count Job ID for Customer ID

Tags: sql, count

Need some help to count the amount of "job_id" for my specifik "customer_id"

The tabel is looking like this:

| Customer_id | Job_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 |
| 1 | 102 |
| 2 | 103 |
| 1 | 104 |
| 1 | 105 |
| 2 | 106 |
| 2 | 107 |

I would like to make a query like this, to get the job_id in order (a count) for the specifik Customer_id:

| Customer_id | Job_id_count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 3 |

Comment: Hint: `GROUP BY`, `COUNT(Job_id)`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need `group by` and `count` aggregate function as follows:

```
select customer_id, count(job_id)
from your_table
group by customer_id;
```

If table contains duplicate `customer_id-job_id` mapping and you want to consider it as a one count only then you can also use `distinct` inside `count` as follows:

```
select customer_id, count(distinct job_id)
from your_table
group by customer_id;
```

Comment: Don't to forget you should also include `order by Customer_Id`